# Accessing sub-item of an item in a nested LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to access an item within an item of nested LinkedList. The `get(index)` function gets you the complete item. Is there any method to get item within an item. 
e.g. I have a nested LinkedList with items as : `[ [[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8],[9]] ]`. When I use `get(0)`, it returns `[[1],[2],[3]]`. Now I want to access item [1], [2] and [3] separately but don't know how to do it. I know that there will be some method to do it but I am new to java, so need help. Thanks.

Comment: Can we have more code to see what object is it

Answer (score 0):

use `get(0).get(index)`, assuming that you are using something like `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method returns you a element so you either assign it to a object and use it from there or just call the methods inline.

1

```
LinkedList foo = myList.get(index);
int bar = foo.get(newIndex);
```

2

```
int foo = myList.get(index).get(newIndex);
```

I rather use the first one because it's easier to read.